# Android slide to do something

Tags: android

I want to do a "slider".

http://inforains.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/slide-to-unlock-android-app.jpg

I mean like similar.

The idea is that when you move the example to the right something going on as in the lockscreen to unlock the screen or turn on the camera.

Google provides a tool for this?

Answer (score 2):

No and apparently, it is [patented by Apple](http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/slide-to-unlock-patented-20100818/).

You can take a look at [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) widget introduced in API level 14 (ICS) - it is the closest match you can find from Android components. You can, however, write your own [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) to achieve it.

Comment: :D :D .Apple patents everything :D

Comment: Hm .. I think it would be better simply to detect the pressure and move the layout.